# Adding temporary exception in osx app in sandbox

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, appstore-sandbox

I want to modify ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist file from my application in sandbox.

I already tried adding temporary exceptions:

> com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write
>   ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist

and as well this one:

> com.apple.security.temporary-exception.shared-preference.read-write
>   com.apple.Finder

but it doesn't work. Without a sandbox my app can modify this file but when I turn it on it doesn't work. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The sandbox was introduced to prevent users from doing such things.

Comment: I wonder if Apple would approve an app that does this.

Comment: Temporary exceptions were introduced to allow such things even in sandbox wasn't it? Or is there something I don't understand about temporary exceptions? I also have serious doubts if Apple would approve this but I wanted to try.